# Laravel 5.5 Why product page is empty?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to display my products. Everything seems fine but products page opening as a blank page in everytime. Where do I mistake ?

Route;

```
Route::get('product/{slug}',['as'=>'product.show','uses'=>'ProductController@getProduct']);
```

Controller;

```
public function getProduct($slug){

        $product = Product::where('product_slug',$slug)->first();

        return view('frontend.product',compact('product'));
    }
```

I tried dd method in my product blade. Then it gave to me this error

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel/storage/framework/views/7cdf86b0b5c552ccae1fab5d7990ec98a9c7cc32.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please show how do you generate a link to this route. Also, check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for latest errors. And make sure you have `resources/views/frontend/product.blade.php`

Comment: Are you sure is the page opening is your frontend directories product page?

Comment: Well, the thing is that, there is no error in log file

Comment: i think router syntax is wrong have you tried die(someting) in start of method

Comment: Yes, I am sure -> https://imgur.com/a/emVbk

Comment: @MudassarZahid I tried in my controller, I have the product slug and I can able to use it. But for a reason, product page is empty (haha :))

Comment: @cervantes please show contents of `product.blade.php`

Comment: Just hard code html, nothing else.. but I tried dd method in my product blade. Could you check my answer, I edited it.

Comment: @cervantes you need to set permissions. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this command to allow Laravel create cache for the views:

```
chmod -R 755 ./storage
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#configuration):

> Directory Permissions
>
> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#configuration

Comment: @cervantes what error do you get now? If the error is same, try to use `777` but only do that on a local computer. Also, what OS do you use? Alternatively try `sudo chgrp -R www-data storage` and `sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage`

Comment: it was same error.. after I tried chmod 777, it worked. Bu this time pc has frozen when the page was loading. Php 7.1 usage reach %98 (what ?)

Comment: @cervantes I don't think it's related to the Laravel app at all.

Comment: You're could be right, I never encountered that error before

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a `php artisan view:clear`
Or setting a `dd('test');` in the method before the view return to see if it even fires.